# show template once data is all loaded using angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Im seeking help. i this is the scenario i have this function wherein it gets all the data from the service and then this data are binded to a ng-carousel bootstrap. the problem that im encountering is that everytime i load the page the template shows right away with empty data. What i wanted to happen is once the data is all loaded that's the only time it will show the template. what the current code does it executes the function however it does not show the template at all once the data are done loading

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isLoaded = false;
    this.getOrders();
  }

  getOrders(page: number = 0): void {
    this.ordersService.getOrders(page).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.orderDetails = data.currentOrders.map((order) => {
          const expensiveProduct = order.expensiveProduct;
          return {
            name: expensiveProduct.name,
            skuId: expensiveProduct.code,
            description: expensiveProduct.omniDisplayName,
            url: expensiveProduct.images[0].url,
            status: order.status.code,
          };
        });
        this.isLoaded = true;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching orders:', error);
      }
    );
  }
```

and on the template this is what i have.

```
    <div class="my-page-orders-banner__container" *ngIf="isLoaded">
  <ngb-carousel
    class="orders-banner"
    [showNavigationArrows]="true"
    [showNavigationIndicators]="false"
    [interval]="false"
    [wrap]="false"
  >
    <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let orderDetail of orderDetails">
      <div class="carousel-item__card">
        <div class="carousel-item__img">
          <img [src]="orderDetail.url" alt="Random first slide" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <div class="carousel-caption__header">{{ orderDetail.status }}</div>
          <div class="carousel-caption__description">
            {{ getTranslations(orderDetail.status) }} {{ translatedOrderStatus }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-carousel>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the initial value of 'isLoaded'?

Comment: Hi nhoyti, "this.orderDetails" could tell you if its loaded or not when recieve data.
ng-template have her own [ngIf]="orderDetails" and inside the ng-template do the ng-container with the *ngFor

Answer (score 1):

Your `getOrders(x:any)` function in `ordersService` may return an empty array, therefore, you need to check whether the `data` has a length and if only, set `isLoaded = true` to render the `carousel` in the template.

```
getOrders(page: number = 0): void {
    this.ordersService.getOrders(page).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        if(data && data.length > 0) {
          this.orderDetails = data.currentOrders.map((order) => {
            const expensiveProduct = order.expensiveProduct;
            return {
              name: expensiveProduct.name,
              skuId: expensiveProduct.code,
              description: expensiveProduct.omniDisplayName,
              url: expensiveProduct.images[0].url,
              status: order.status.code,
            };
          });
          this.isLoaded = true;
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching orders:', error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the getOrders method to set isLoaded to true only after the data is fetched successfully:

```
 getOrders(page: number = 0): void {
  this.ordersService.getOrders(page).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      this.orderDetails = data.currentOrders.map((order) => {
        // map order details
      });
    },
    (error) => {
      console.error('Error fetching orders:', error);
    },
    () => {
      // This block will be executed when the 
          observable completes successfully
      this.isLoaded = true;
    }
  );
}
```